# hive left outer join long running

Tags: hive, mapreduce, query-optimization, hiveql, reduce

Hortonworks HDP 2.3.0 - Hive 0.14

`Table T1 ( partition on col1, no bucket, ORC )`  app 120 million rows & 6GB datasize
`Table T2 ( partition on col2, no bucket, ORC )` app 200 M rows & 6MB datasize

```
T1 left outer join on t2 ( t1.col3 = t2.col3 )
```

The above query is long running in the last reducer phase in both tez & mr mode.
I also tried auto convert true / false & explicit mapjoin.

Still the query is running in the last reducer phase, never ending.

FYI - If data size of T2 is either 9k or 1GB, the query finishes.

Comment: Um. Some more verbs and explanatory text would be nice. The question is rather hard to understand as it stands.

Comment: I am trying to perform left outer join with big table ( 6 GB) vs small table ( 6 MB). In both tez & mr mode, this left outer join never finishes. In any kind if configuration ( auto convert true / auto convert false ) the execution is stuck in the last reducer stage of the MapReduce Job / TEZ job.

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe is that there are too many bytes/rows per reducer. If the application execution is stuck in the last **single** reducer then it's most probably data skew. To check it, select top 5 col3 from both tables, skew is when there are a lot of records with the same key value(say 30%). If it's a skew then try to join separately skew key then UNION ALL with all other keys join. Something like this:

```
select * from
T1 left outer join on t2 on ( t1.col3 = t2.col3 ) and t1.col3=SKEW_VALUE
union all
select * from
T1 left outer join on t2 on ( t1.col3 = t2.col3 ) and t1.col3<>SKEW_VALUE
```

If the application execution is stuck in the last reducer stage, not a single reducer or few reducers, then check bytes.per.reducer hive setting, maybe it's too high.

```
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=67108864;
```

Comment: Hi All Thanks for your response. There was huge duplicate values on join key (col3), as a result 37 TB of data is being written which makes reducer to run for long time. After filtering the duplicates, the query ran better

Answer (score 0):

But have you tried giving size to auto convert join, try giving size > than of small table that can be fit into memory.

> set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size = 10000000;