# skew data causing long running query in hive

Tags: performance, hive

I am running a hive query like tableA left join tableB on tableA.col1=tableB.col1 and tableA.col2=tableB.col2. tableA is having 1.8 billion data and tableB is having 31 million records. Now the last reducers in my join is not getting completed and it is running for long.

It may be because of skew data. I did tried MAPJOIN and the query failed because of huge data volume for tableA. Is there any other options these can be handled in a better way?

The task which I can see running for long is as below

```
reduce > copy task(attempt_1498868574233_185232_m_001336_0 succeeded at 8.94 MB/s) Aggregated copy rate(1121 of 2532 at 108.94 MB/s)
```

What exactly it is trying to do in that step?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414611/2700344

Comment: @leftjoin, no need for manual work-around. Hive supports skewed join.

Answer (score 1):

set `hive.optimize.skewjoin` to `true`

> **hive.optimize.skewjoin**
>   Default Value: false
>   Added In: Hive 0.6.0
>   Whether to enable skew join optimization.

You might also want to tune `hive.skewjoin.key`, `hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks` and `hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split`.

> **hive.skewjoin.key**
>   Default Value: 100000
>   Added In: Hive 0.6.0
>   Determine if we get a skew key in join. If we see more than the
>   specified number of rows with the same key in join operator, we think
>   the key as a skew join key.
>
> **hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks**
>   Default Value: 10000
>   Added In: Hive 0.6.0
>   Determine the number of map task used in the follow up map
>   join job for a skew join. It should be used together with
>   hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split to perform a fine grained control.
>
> **hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split**
>   Default Value: 33554432
>   Added In: Hive 0.6.0
>   Determine the number of map task at most used in the follow
>   up map join job for a skew join by specifying the minimum split size.
>   It should be used together with hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks to
>   perform a fine grained control.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties